# WebSockets over HTTP/2, and GOAWAY

Tags: websocket, http2

I am interested in how WebSockets over HTTP/2 work on browsers (Firefox, specifically, since that 's the only one I'm aware of which supports Websockets over H2) with GOAWAYs.

Now, I know that GOAWAYs are connection-level events, and if IIUC, a WebSocket/H2 connection is actually a single H2 stream which has been upgraded.

Let's say that we  nowget a GOAWAY from the server - do we expect the browser to just close the H2 stream which was supporting the WebSocket connection with a `CloseEvent` with code 1001? Is there some other event which gets fired/which needs to be added to the WebSocket API, for eg, `ongoaway`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, I know that GOAWAYs are connection-level events, and if IIUC, a WebSocket/H2 connection is actually a single H2 stream which has been upgraded.

A single HTTP/2 connection may have multiple HTTP/2 streams, each one possibly being a WebSocket over HTTP/2 "upgraded" stream (see [this section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8441#section-1)).

The goal is to use one single TCP connection carry possibly multiple protocols, so a situation where some stream are normal HTTP/2 and some are WebSocket over HTTP/2 is possible.

When connection level GOAWAY is sent by the server, I would expect the client to react as specified in [this section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-6.8).

In particular the server may send a "graceful" GOAWAY, so clients don't open new streams.

When the server is about to send the GOAWAY, it should arrange to send a terminal (i.e. `endStream=true`) `DATA` frame containing a WebSocket `Close` frame, which would result in a `CloseEvent` in the browser.

I don't think any event should be added to browsers' WebSocket APIs, the transport over HTTP/2 should be completely transparent for client applications, like it is transparent using HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2 when using `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch()`.